# How do you represent a set multiplied with itself?

Tags: notation

Let's say my set is $S = \{5, 13, 17, 29, 37, 41, 53, 61, 73, 89, 97, \ldots\}$
I want to create a new set where each element is multiplied by every other element.

So loosely speaking $T = S \times S$ (Kind of like a cartesian or cross product)

So
$$T = \{25, 65, 85, 125, 145, 169, 185, 205, 221, 265, 289, \ldots\}$$

But it's not really a Cartesian product because a Cartesian product would have pairs like $(5,5)$, $(5,13)$ as elements.
What notation can I use to express $T$ compactly?

Update: Actually, I want to update my question a little bit.
Actually, my set $S$ is infinite but let's assume it to be finite for a sec. So $S = \{5, 13, 17\}$.

In that case, $T$ is not just $\{25, 65, 85, 169, 221, 289\}$. Instead it is
$T = \{25, 65, 85, 125, 169, 221, 289, 325, \ldots\}$. In other words, $T$ is not finite but infinite. This is because it needs to have multiples of elements that were added recently. So it also needs to have $25\times5=125$, $25\times13=325$, $125\times5=625$, and so on.

Is there a precedence for constructing a set like this?

What notation can I use to express this?

Comment: Could you more explain the set $T$?

Comment: $T = \{ a \mid \exists b, c \in S (a=b \times c) \}$

Comment: The notation $S \cdot S$ and $S^2$ is also used; see (for example) *Additive Combinatorics* by Terry Tao and Van Vu

Comment: https://oeis.org/search?q=25%2C+65%2C+85%2C+125%2C+145%2C+169%2C+185%2C+205%2C+221%2C+265%2C+289&language=english&go=Search

Answer (score 3):

Given a semigroup $S$, the power set ${\cal P}(S)$ is also a semigroup for the product defined, for all $X, Y \in {\cal P}(S)$, by
$$
XY = \{xy \mid x \in X, y \in Y\}
$$
You seem to be in this exact situation, where $S$ is $\Bbb N$ under multiplication. You could briefly recall this definition and then use it.

EDIT. You modified your question, making my first answer irrelevant (not a good idea). With the new definition, it looks like your $T$ is the subsemigroup of $({\Bbb N},\times)$ generated by $S$.